# Why can not init facebook with nativescript-facebook

Tags: facebook, nativescript

I use nativescript-facebook from https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-facebook and after update nativescript to version 6.1.2, I can not use it's and show error "Error: The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.". How to fix its

Android-menifest

`import * as app from "tns-core-modules/application";
import { init } from "nativescript-facebook";`

`app.on(app.launchEvent, function()`
`{
    init("2085919111703987");
});`

`app.run({ moduleName: "app-root" });`

Comment: Did you update your facebook plugin too? Which version of plugin you are using now and which platform you are facing the issue with?

Comment: Fix with this
https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-facebook/issues/214#issuecomment-539987343